# Looping through rows and recording matching pairs

Tags: r, social-networking

I'm trying to compile an edge list to be used for a social network graph based on a table that looks something like this:

```
CompanyID  ProjectID  Year
   A         1        2010
   B         3        2011
   C         1        2010
   D         5        2012
   E         1        2010
```

The idea is to have a list of vertices (companies) that have worked on the same project. So, given the data above, I'd have

```
CompanyA    CompanyB
   A           C
   A           E
   C           E
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: Why A-C / A-E / C-E and not E-A / C-E / A-C or any other combination for CompanyA or CompanyB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your data frame `x`:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='CompanyID  ProjectID  Year
A         1        2010
B         3        2011
C         1        2010
D         5        2012
E         1        2010')
```

Choose those entries that have multiple values for `ProjectID`:

```
(mx <- x[ave(seq(nrow(x)), x$ProjectID, FUN=length) > 1,])
##   CompanyID ProjectID Year
## 1         A         1 2010
## 3         C         1 2010
## 5         E         1 2010
```

Now for the magic:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        by(mx, mx$ProjectID,
           FUN=function(mx) 
             t(apply(combn(as.numeric(mx$CompanyID), 2), 2, 
                function(x) levels(mx$CompanyID)[x]
               )
             )
        )
)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] "A"  "C" 
## [2,] "A"  "E" 
## [3,] "C"  "E"
```

With your example data, you get the same result without wrapping up in `do.call(rbind ...` but that is needed in the case where there are multiple ProjectID's in play.